# How to test generic function with table driven tests (Go)?

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, generics, table-driven

We were brainstorming possible ways of testing generic functions using table driven tests.
It seems pretty complicated at the first glance.

What we wanted to achieve is to have a field in the test table struct that can be of whatever type that is accepted by the generic function. It seems however, that you can't use `any` interface for that.

We came up with the following solution:

***Example function***:

```
func PtrTo[T any](t T) *T {
    return &t
}
```

***Example test***:

```
func TestPtrTo(t *testing.T) {

    string1 := "abcd"

    trueVar := true

    testCases := []struct {
        testDescription string
        input           interface{}
        expectedOutput  interface{}
    }{
        {
            testDescription: "string",
            input:           string1,
            expectedOutput:  &string1,
        },
        {
            testDescription: "bool",
            input:           trueVar,
            expectedOutput:  &trueVar,
        },
    }

    for _, testCase := range testCases {
        t.Run(testCase.testDescription, func(t *testing.T) {
            switch concreteTypeInput := testCase.input.(type) {
            case string:
                output := PtrTo(concreteTypeInput)
                assert.Equal(t, testCase.expectedOutput, output)
            case bool:
                output := PtrTo(concreteTypeInput)
                assert.Equal(t, testCase.expectedOutput, output)
            default:
                t.Error("Unexpected type. Please add the type to the switch case")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

It doesn't really feel optimal, though.

What do you think of this solution?

Do you see any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to table-test generics the way you describe.

The code is generic: if it compiles in the first place, then you have the compile-time guarantee that it will behave exactly the same for all values of `T` that satisfy the constraint(s).

In other words, it's pointless to test that the return type of `PtrTo` is `*bool` when `T` is `bool`. The compiler already type-checked it for you.

It makes sense to test different input types only if:

- there is type-based conditional logic within the function body, i.e. a type switch, so that the function output could effectively differ
- `T` is constrained by a union and the function body makes use of operators that have different semantics based on the type, e.g. `+` operator with number types (sum) or with string types (concatenation)

When you have broad constraints like `any` and the semantics of the function body are the same for all `T`s, just test it with a random type and call it a day.

Answer (score -1):

A templated helper function could give you the semantics I think you're looking for:

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp"
)

type testCase[T any] struct {
    desc string
    in   T
    want *T
}

func ptrToTest[T any](t *testing.T, tc testCase[T]) {
    t.Helper()
    t.Run(tc.desc, func(t *testing.T) {
        got := PtrTo(tc.in)
        if diff := cmp.Diff(tc.want, got); diff != "" {
            t.Fatalf("got %v, want %v", got, tc.want)
        }
    })
}

func TestPtrTo(t *testing.T) {
    string1 := "abcd"
    ptrToTest(t, testCase[string]{
        desc: "string",
        in:   string1,
        want: &string1,
    })

    trueVar := true
    ptrToTest(t, testCase[bool]{
        desc: "bool",
        in:   trueVar,
        want: &trueVar,
    })
}
```

That being said, I agree with @blackgreen that the `PtrTo` function is too trivial for a test like this to be meaningful. Hopefully this is useful for more complicated logic!